# how to read hashtags in python?

Tags: python, configuration-files

I'm trying to read a config file like:

```
[servers]
    [germany]
        test=1
        safd=134i
    [at]
        ip=asfd
```

and i am trying to parse the config

```
import configparser

p = configparser.ConfigParser()

print ("p.read: \t", p.read('config.cfg'))
print ("secions: \t", p.sections())
for i in p.sections():
    print(i)
```

OUTPUT:

```
p.read:          ['config.cfg']
secions:         ['servers', 'germany', 'at']
servers
germany
at
```

and i want to walk through the sections and sub sections like

```
for i in p.sections(): 
  print(i.[0][1])
```

or something like this.

is the configfile wrong? i mean how can i handle this
in python?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[The `configparser` module is for parsing INI files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), and [INI files are not hierarchical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Hierarchy), so the indentation in the config file is simply ignored.

If you have control over the format of the config files, you're probably better off using [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).

JSON can be parsed using the `json` module from standard library.

YAML can be parsed using the 3rd party `pyyaml` package (that you'll need to install with `pip`), which has a similar API to the `json` module and can be imported with `import yaml`.